# HTML списки проблема с выводом в одну строку

Tags: html5, css3, меню, xhtml

Здравствуйте. Довольно странная проблема. При выводе списка в горизонтальную строку, он у меня выводится во второй ряд. Подскажите, как исправить эту проблему?
Заранее спасибо!

[image: Скриншот сайта с проблемой]

```css
body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, "Times New Roman";
font-size: 12pt;
background-color: #333333;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1060px) {
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1060px;
}
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Geneva";
  src: url("../fonts/Geneva.eot");
  src: local('O'), 
  url("../fonts/Geneva.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  url("../fonts/Geneva.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/Geneva.ttf") format("truetype"), 
  url("../fonts/Geneva.svg#PT Serif") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Comfortaa";
  src: url("../fonts/Comfortaa.eot");
  src: local('O'), 
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.ttf") format("truetype"), 
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.svg#PT Serif") format("svg");
}

#logo {
background: url(../images/bg_logo.jpg);
height: 155px;
}

#logo #logotype p {
padding: 40px 0 0 60px;
margin-bottom: -15px;
}

#logo #logotype .big_letter {
font-family: Comfortaa;
font-size: 38pt;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 0;
}

#logo #logotype .small_letter {
font-family: Geneva;
font-size: 7.5pt;
color: #535353;
padding-top: 0;
letter-spacing: 2.2px;
}

#logo #topmenu table {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: -80px;
left: 2px;
padding: 0;
}

#logo #topmenu table  td.topmenu_border_last {
border-right: none;
}

#logo #topmenu table td a {
font-size: 10pt;
font-family: Verdana;
text-decoration: none;
color: #616161;
vertical-align: text-top;
}

#logo #topmenu table td {
border-right: 1px solid #363636;
padding: 0 15px;
}

#topmenuright {
float: right;
position: relative;
top: -117px;
right: -6px;
}

#search {
width: 380px;
height: 37px;
}

#logo #search input {
float: left;
border: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
width: 263px;
height: 36px;
padding: 0 37px 1px 15px;
background-color: #121212;
color: #5d5d5d;
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
outline: none;
border-radius: 7px;
font-size: 8pt;
}

input[type="submit"] {
width: 26px;
height: 29px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: -37px;
background: url("../images/hwsearch_03.png") no-repeat;
margin-top: 5px;
}

#logo #topmenuright table {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td img {
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td p.tablenadpis {
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
font-size: 10pt;
color: #6e6e6e;
padding-left: 5px;
vertical-align: text-top;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td.b1 a, #logo #topmenuright table td.b2 a {
border-right: 1px solid #4b4a4a;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td a {
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
color: #a9a9a9;
font-size: 70%;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 4px;
}

#mainmenu {
height: 43px;
background: url("../images/hwbg2_02.jpg") repeat-x;
}

#mainmenu ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#mainmenu ul li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
}

#mainmenu ul li a {
font-family: Arial, "Times New Roman";
color: #9c9c9c;
padding: 11px 15px;
text-decoration: none; 
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <div id="logotype">
      <p class="big_letter">Box&amp;Cube</p>
      <p class="small_letter">CREATE &amp; INNOVATE SOLUTIONS</p>
    </div>
    <div id="topmenu">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
          </td>
          <td class="topmenu_border_last">
            <a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="topmenuright">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="images/hw_03.png" alt="Emblema" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="tablenadpis">Please subscribe to:</p>
          </td>
          <td class="b1">
            <a href="#">Posts</a>
          </td>
          <td class="b2">
            <a href="#">Comments</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#">Email
              </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div id="search">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="search">
          <input type="text" name="" value="Enter Search Keyword" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Search Keyword';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Search Keyword') this.value='';" class="inputblock" />
          <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>WEB PROFESSIONALS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>BUSINESS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>WEB DESIGN</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>MEDIA</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>ENTERTAINMENT</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>NON-PROFIT</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>INSTITUTIONS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>PORTALS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Судя по картинке, меню оказалось внутри блока, который закончился аккурат перед полем поиска. Но чтобы не гадать, добавьте в вопрос свой HTML код.

Comment: Gleb Kemarsky, добавил

Comment: Интересно то, что до и после того, что добавили.

Comment: Gleb Kemarsky, код CSS весь нужен?

Comment: Заменил ваш код на сниппет. В нынешнем виде всё работает. Значит, надо добавить то, от чего меню ломается. Вы какие стили подцепляете помимо собственного CSS?

Comment: Gleb Kemarsky, а что добавить? Я не понимаю от чего это. Сейчас вставлю весь код css. Никакие больше, кроме своего. От @media может быть?

Comment: Gleb Kemarsky, может быть что-то из того, что прислал мешать этому списку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше меню оказалось ограничено блоком `.topmenuright`. То, что он наверху - только кажется, а на самом деле у него относительное позиционирование. Поэтому место, которое он занимал в вёрстке, остаётся занятым. Меню наталкивается на эту преграду и переходит на вторую строку.

Можно этот блок поставить первым в `<div id="logo">` и убрать у него всё, кроме  `float: right;`:

```css
body {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, "Times New Roman";
font-size: 12pt;
background-color: #333333;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1060px) {
body {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1060px;
}
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Geneva";
  src: url("../fonts/Geneva.eot");
  src: local('O'), 
  url("../fonts/Geneva.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  url("../fonts/Geneva.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/Geneva.ttf") format("truetype"), 
  url("../fonts/Geneva.svg#PT Serif") format("svg");
}

@font-face {
font-family: "Comfortaa";
  src: url("../fonts/Comfortaa.eot");
  src: local('O'), 
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.woff") format("woff"),
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.ttf") format("truetype"), 
  url("../fonts/Comfortaa.svg#PT Serif") format("svg");
}

#logo {
background: url(../images/bg_logo.jpg);
height: 155px;
}

#logo #logotype p {
padding: 40px 0 0 60px;
margin-bottom: -15px;
}

#logo #logotype .big_letter {
font-family: Comfortaa;
font-size: 38pt;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 0;
}

#logo #logotype .small_letter {
font-family: Geneva;
font-size: 7.5pt;
color: #535353;
padding-top: 0;
letter-spacing: 2.2px;
}

#logo #topmenu table {
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
top: -80px;
left: 2px;
padding: 0;
}

#logo #topmenu table  td.topmenu_border_last {
border-right: none;
}

#logo #topmenu table td a {
font-size: 10pt;
font-family: Verdana;
text-decoration: none;
color: #616161;
vertical-align: text-top;
}

#logo #topmenu table td {
border-right: 1px solid #363636;
padding: 0 15px;
}

#topmenuright {
float: right;
/*
position: relative;
top: -117px;
right: -6px;
*/
}

#search {
width: 380px;
height: 37px;
}

#logo #search input {
float: left;
border: none;
}

input[type="text"] {
width: 263px;
height: 36px;
padding: 0 37px 1px 15px;
background-color: #121212;
color: #5d5d5d;
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
outline: none;
border-radius: 7px;
font-size: 8pt;
}

input[type="submit"] {
width: 26px;
height: 29px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: -37px;
background: url("../images/hwsearch_03.png") no-repeat;
margin-top: 5px;
}

#logo #topmenuright table {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td img {
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td p.tablenadpis {
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
font-size: 10pt;
color: #6e6e6e;
padding-left: 5px;
vertical-align: text-top;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td.b1 a, #logo #topmenuright table td.b2 a {
border-right: 1px solid #4b4a4a;
}

#logo #topmenuright table td a {
font-family: Verdana, Arial;
color: #a9a9a9;
font-size: 70%;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 4px;
}

#mainmenu {
height: 43px;
background: url("../images/hwbg2_02.jpg") repeat-x;
}

#mainmenu ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#mainmenu ul li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
}

#mainmenu ul li a {
font-family: Arial, "Times New Roman";
color: #9c9c9c;
padding: 11px 15px;
text-decoration: none; 
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 11pt;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="logo">
    <div id="topmenuright">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="images/hw_03.png" alt="Emblema" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="tablenadpis">Please subscribe to:</p>
          </td>
          <td class="b1">
            <a href="#">Posts</a>
          </td>
          <td class="b2">
            <a href="#">Comments</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#">Email
              </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div id="search">
        <form action="#" method="post" id="search">
          <input type="text" name="" value="Enter Search Keyword" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter Search Keyword';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Search Keyword') this.value='';" class="inputblock" />
          <input type="submit" name="" value="" class="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="logotype">
      <p class="big_letter">Box&amp;Cube</p>
      <p class="small_letter">CREATE &amp; INNOVATE SOLUTIONS</p>
    </div>
    <div id="topmenu">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a href="#"><span>Home</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#"><span>About</span></a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a>
          </td>
          <td class="topmenu_border_last">
            <a href="#"><span>Blog</span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>WEB PROFESSIONALS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>BUSINESS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>WEB DESIGN</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>MEDIA</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>ENTERTAINMENT</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>NON-PROFIT</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>INSTITUTIONS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>PORTALS</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Gleb Kemarsky, я не убрал, а добавил туда:
 height: 1px;     
Все сразу получилось! Так тоже можно? Если же я уберу то что Вы сказали, как я тогда его подниму и сдвину тот блок?

Comment: @MaksIvasenko Чем меньше неожиданных хитростей, тем легче сопровождать сайт.